# Jquery: "G is undefined" error while using string.match

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using Jquery 1.3 and this is the code i've isolated the code that throws an error in firebug as follows: "G is undefined"

```
    var product = $("#id :selected");         // This is a dropdown
    var prodTxt = product.text();             // Returns string as expected
    var price = prodTxt.match(/\$[0-9]{3}/);  // Commenting this out removes the error. 
    //var price = prodTxt.match(/\$[0-9]*/);
```

I thought it had something to do with the */ in the regex but still doesn't work.

The regex looks for any price as indicated by a dollar sign.

I suppose there are other workarounds and I may just do that, but I'm still confused as to what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

### UPDATE-SOLVED

```
var price = String(prodTxt.match(/\$[0-9]{3}/));
```

Not sure why that worked. I'm sure someone much smarter than me could explain how not typecasting it infuriated the ominous "g" variable.

Comment: I don't think that's where you're getting the error; that line is not a jQuery call, though `product.text()` is.

Comment: You are converting the Array (or null) that is returned into a string. So the issue was likely with how you were using the Array or null value.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get that error. Just be aware that `.match()` returns an array, so you may need to access the match by its index `[0]`.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/dJ294/

```
$("#id").change(function() {
    var product = $("#id :selected");         // This is a dropdown
    var prodTxt = product.text();             // Returns string as expected
    var price = prodTxt.match(/\$[0-9]{3}/);  // Commenting this out removes the error. 
    //var price = prodTxt.match(/\$[0-9]*/);

         // Access match by its index number
    $('body').append('<br/>' + price[0]);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes after the match line. Most likely, it's caused when you try to use the "price" variable as a string when match returns an array.